# Rake task in staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task, staging

I'm trying to rake a task in staging environment, so I've created a db.rake file in lib/tasks folder. For sure I'm missing something, but for some reason is not setting staging environment as it should. How do I know? Because I'm trying to print User.all to find every user but what I get is an empty array. In console I put rake db:clean_user_vitcords RAILS_ENV=staging

This is the task I've created at db.rake

```
namespace :db do
  desc "TODO"
  task clean_user_vitcords: :environment do
    ap "entro aqui"
    ap Rails.env
    users = User.all
    ap users.to_a
    users.each do |user|
      user.vitcords.reject! { |vitcord_id| Vitcord.find(vitcord_id).count == 0 }
      user.save
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the output in console

```
"entro aqui"
"staging"
[]
```

Comment: Are you sure what you have users in DB for staging environment? Could you check it in `rails console` ?

Comment: Yes Oleg, I've checked previously that there are users in database in staging

Comment: @DavidSoler What is ap?

Comment: @DavidSoler One more thing to check is config/database.yml. Make sure staging database info is correct.

Comment: You were right Oleg, I was pointing to the wrong database. It was not staging, it was preproduction. My mistake.